# Is it bad practice to add CR/LF's to logging messages to improve readability

Tags: java, logging, owasp

We have a method which we use to log java exceptions in a log file. The method allows the caller to pass variables they wish to be shown in the log message for debugging purposes and uses inserts blank lines and tabs to make the message stand out and be more readable.

However, all of the recommendations I see to prevent *Log Forging* attacks recommend stripping all of the CRLF's out of the logging message.

Is it considered bad practice to have CRLF's in a logging message? This method is only used internally and any user supplied information can be sanitized before being passed to the method.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "bad."  It could break tools that expect to parse output in a single line, but if that's not a requirement then don't worry about it.  (And `CR` is kinda passe, just `LF` will do.)

Comment: Not sure enough of myself to "answer", but I think the problem is when you leave CRLF in user messages, not when you put them in.  The problem comes when a user injects a CRLF between two parts that should be together.

Comment: If the concern is specifically a log forging attack, then you want to strip newlines from the input, not newlines inserted by your logging code. In your logging method you could remove newlines from the passed-in parameters and still log them each on a separate line.

Comment: @markspace I actually use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in my code but I used CRLF in my question because the attack is referred to as CRLF Injection.

Comment: if every log is a simple line you can easily search for interesting logs with tools like `grep`. A grep search becomes less useful when the log entries are spread over multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generally - yes.

while this seems a nice feature at first glance, you should consider the following potential complications:

- depending on exactly how this is implemented, if you hand the underlying logging framework multiple lines as multiple logging invocations your statement could get interleaved with other concurrent logging statements, making the resulting log less readable
- various log-parsing tools tend to assume one line == one statement. most know how to account for exception stack traces (that are multi line) but not much beyond, so you may find yourself having to delve into things like ELK stack / loggly configs to teach it about your fancy multiline statements.
- complications around terminals with different widths (if youre printing to console)

Comment: The method passes a single String to the logging method which outputs the String to a text file.  Locally we look at the log file with a text editor.  For dev, test and prod we use Splunk and it has no issue with showing the String as one line.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real problem is that you're tightly coupling the message you output with the medium you're expecting it to be stored in (a plain-text file). I'd recommend looking into structured logging frameworks, and more powerful "Sinks" for your structured logs to go to, so you can analyze your logs without relying on message-formatting tricks.